# Sticky footer without page wrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Following is the fiddle which works fine if the content above the footer is wrapped in `page-wrap` and on less content the footer sticks to bottom else there will be the scroll. Is there a way to make this fiddle in a way so it should not depend on `page-wrap` and I only have to apply the css on the footer only. I am requesting this because there are over 50 pages made in this way and by adding ss to only footer. I only have to change the header file for the footer.

http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/uwJjr

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
    margin-bottom: -142px; 
}
.page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  /* .push must be the same height as footer */
    height: 142px; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED:**

http://jsfiddle.net/bWTwL/1178/

add this code to your jquery:

```
$('.page-wrap').css('min-height',($(window).height()-142)+'px');
```

and this is your CSS:

```
/* Mostly: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/ */

* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.page-wrap {
  /* equal to footer height */
    height:auto;
}
.site-footer {
    background: orange;
    height:142px;
    display:block;

}
```

without `.page-wrap:after`

Comment: Your code made the footer sticky and not pushing it down when there is more content

Comment: check the answer again

Comment: تشکر امین برای انجام آن راه من می خواهم به انجام. آیا ما می توانیم آن را انجام دهد بدون دخالت جاوا اسکریپت را بیش از حد؟ این راه حل بسیار کار می کنند.

Comment: unfortunately not, or at least I don't know a way of doing this without jQuery or JS

Comment: p.s. your Farsi is awful! :D ;)